# Update command : - ORA-01427: "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: oracle

My queries:

```
update bl1_customer bl
  set bl.CYCLE_CODE=(select c.BILL_CYCLE
                       from canba_bs3 c
                       inner join bl1_customer bl
                         on c.CUSTOMER_ID=bl.CUSTOMER_ID)
  where exists (select c.BILL_CYCLE
                  from canba_bs3 c
                  inner join bl1_customer bl
                    on c.CUSTOMER_ID=bl.CUSTOMER_ID) and
        bl.status='O';

update bl1_customer bl
  set bl.CYCLE_CODE=(select c.BILL_CYCLE
                       from canba_bs3 c
                       inner join bl1_customer bl
                         on c.CUSTOMER_ID=bl.CUSTOMER_ID)
  where exists (select c.BILL_CYCLE
                  from canba_bs3 c
                  inner join bl1_customer bl
                    on c.CUSTOMER_ID=bl.CUSTOMER_ID) and
        bl.status='O';
```

Error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Please help me to resolve it

Comment: both updates are identical? or I am missing a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You tried to execute a SQL statement that contained a SQL subquery that returns more than one row.
You should check the update condition. Try to run it as a SELECT query and see the results.

Comment: I have done it already, it is returning more than one but I have used exists also

Comment: Are you sure that the result of the this is limited to one row:
(select c.BILL_CYCLE from canba_bs3 c inner join bl1_customer bl on c.CUSTOMER_ID=bl.CUSTOMER_ID)

Comment: it is returning more than one

Comment: So you should fix that subquery to returning only one row.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is raised because the subquery in the SET clause, i.e.

```
select c.BILL_CYCLE
  from canba_bs3 c
  inner join bl1_customer bl
  on c.CUSTOMER_ID=bl.CUSTOMER_ID
```

returns more than one row.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a correlated sub-query:

```
update bl1_customer bl
set bl.CYCLE_CODE=( select c.BILL_CYCLE
                    from   canba_bs3 c
                    where  c.CUSTOMER_ID=bl.CUSTOMER_ID )
where bl.status='O'
AND   EXISTS(       select 1
                    from   canba_bs3 c
                    where  c.CUSTOMER_ID=bl.CUSTOMER_ID );
```

You also need to make sure that the table `canba_bs3` only contains one row per customer.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same alias `bl` for the update table and the inner join table in the subquery. the inner table will have precedence when you use that alias.

consequently, there is no restriction relating the subquery with the updated row, so the subquery will return all values for every updated row.

if there is at most one BILL_CYCLE for each bl1_customer you could rephrase your update this way:

```
update bl1_customer bl
   set bl.CYCLE_CODE=(select c.BILL_CYCLE
                        from canba_bs3 c
                       WHERE c.CUSTOMER_ID=bl.CUSTOMER_ID)
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM canba_bs3 WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=bl.CUSTOMER_ID)
       and bl.status='O';
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, several things to point out.

Name scoping. In both cases your nested select includes a reference to the same table with the same alias as the main statement. If you think that this ties them together you are wrong. The "b1" alias in the outer scope loses effectiveness in the nested query because the local alias then takes precedence. So, your statment as given can be explained in english to be:

"Update the bl1_customer table set the cycle code equal to the cycle code for all cycles tied to customers, for every row where the status is `0`and if there exists any bill cycle records for any customers"

What you are trying to do, I would imagine is "Update the bl1_customer table with the cycle_Code = to the cycle_code found in canba_bs3 for this customer."

This can still not describe a complete solution as it does not answer:

Question: If there is no such record for a given bl1_Customer in canba_bs3, do you update the cycle_code to null for this customer? Or leave any pre-existing value in that field?

Question: If there is more than one such record for a given bl1_Customer in canba_bs3, which you update the cycle_code field with?

Now, if we assume that there can be at most one record in canba_b3 for each customer_bl1, then the answer given by 1010 is correct.

But asking us to solve a problem without giving us the intent of the statement is, frankly, a wasted exercise.